# Make Ad-hoc builds in Xcode 6 without signing in to developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ad-hoc-distribution

Before Xcode 6, it was sufficient to provide only a *.p12 certificate and *.mobileprovision file to Xcode in order to export an *.ipa file for Ad Hoc builds.

Xcode 6 opens the Organizer as usual when the archive is ready, but when I press the "Export" button, the Organizer asks to select a Development Team.  It does not allow me to proceed without one even though I have *.p12 and *.mobileprovision installed.

> To save for Ad Hoc Development, select a Development Team to use for provisioning:

I know that a developer account could be exported from Xcode accounts pane, but there is a problem with that.  It exports all certificates and mobileprovision files associated with it.  This includes other profiles that I don't want to include (because I want to share the resulting export with a project team and don't want to include non-relevant profiles).

Is there any way to avoid this "helpful" feature and just export the relevant *.p12 and *.mobileprovision?

Comment: Same question. Waiting for the answers!

Comment: Also same question. Any updates on this yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select "Use local signing assets" in the accounts drop down.[image]

Comment: Although Organizer won't ask you to select a specific provisioning profile, it seems like it proposes the profile matching by bundle id. At least it worked for me, I haven't tested whether it works for whildcard profiles though.

Comment: There is not the list when no one user login in Xcode 7.2.1. How to handle it?

Answer (score 21):

If you are using Testflight to upload adhoc builds, it's easier. Install the Testflight app for Mac and run it. Whenever you do an archive in Xcode, it auto shows a popup whether to upload it. You need not export the build from Xcode and avoid signing in to developer account.

Alternatively, if you don't want to distribute on Testflight, you can right click (or option click) on the build in Xcode > Organizer and select "Show in Finder" and right click the archived file for "Show package contents" and get the .app. Put the .app inside a directory called Payload and zip up the the file to Payload.zip. Rename Payload.zip to myapp.ipa to distribute manually.

Comment: I'm admin (not Agent) to my developer account. But still am having the same problem. I could not able to make builds as I made in Xcode 5.1.2

Comment: thanks Sasi kiran Malladi, it worked. Very helpful answer

Answer (score 19):

Edit: A long time has passed since this answer. As for now I suggest using Fastlane for building the app from command line - with proper configuration it won't require signing with dev account.

Original answer below:

I don't know how to do it in xcode, however - I've managed to do it using command line tools:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -scheme SCHEME_NAME -workspace Workspace.xcworkspace clean archive -archivePath build/App
xcodebuild -configuration Release -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "build/App.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/App.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME"
```

Comment: Seems like a nice approach @mlepicki ... I'm getting this error error: no provisioning profile matches '' ** EXPORT FAILED **. What's the first instruction you posted for?

Comment: It's creating *.xcarchive, so if it fails I suggest checking provisioning profile settings in your project. I've also added switch for choosing Release configuration in command above

Comment: I found the similar solution in great description step by steps, it really very help full for beginners too hera at http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/10/making-ad-hoc-build-from-command-line.html

Comment: I've also summarized some more information in form of blog post, enjoy: http://codingfingers.com/building-xcode-ios-projects-and-creating-ipa-file-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Facing this error : No profiles for 'project' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'project'.

Comment: This answer is kind of outdated now. I suggest just switching to fastlane https://fastlane.tools/

Answer (score 4):

We were having the same problem. I tried building the project and making the archive using Xcode 6 and after that I go to the Organizer window of XCode 5 and export the adhoc build from there. It works fine.

Comment: its time to use updated Xcode 6 its public and no need to have 2 Xcode. I face the same issue and found command line solution for that. here are the steps to create build in Xcode 6...at I found the similar solution in great description step by steps, it really very help full for beginners too hera at http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/10/making-ad-hoc-build-from-command-line.html

Comment: just make sure your provisioning profile/certificate are fine.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26497744/1500634

Xcode Version 6.1
TestFlight Version 1.0 (320)

Answer (score 0):

Download a previous version of Xcode, I just got the version 4.6.3 and it worked fine so far.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: @Jitesh already suggested to use previous version of Xcode to make Ad Hoc builds, you even don't have to download ancient versions, having Xcode 5 in enough for this approach. However it will double the space taken to store Xcodes and all their facilities, and it looks like they could interfere each other in some situations. At least I noticed that Xcode 5 started to use UI of Xcode 6 meanwhile in About Xcode it told that it's still 5.x version

Comment: AppStore does not accept builds generated with Xcode < 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i use **Unity 5.0.1p1** with **Vuforia 4.2.3**.
So, it have a **QCARWrapper.bundle** on **"Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources"**

I delete it, and export. Works!!!

I do this only for **EXPORT FOR AD HOC**.

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, you need to create a new **Distribution** profile, specific for **Ad Hoc Deployment**.
This can be found in the classic member center, but it is a new type of certificate.

You can then select which devices can be used to test the app as ou would do with a developer profile.

Alternatively you can use the TestFlight solution provided by Apple with iOS 8 to enable your user to have access to prereleases.

[image: Screen capture of provisioning profile creation]

Comment: I'm aware that you need Distribution profile to make ad hoc builds, the question wasn't about it.

Comment: as you see , this question is about making build without an account!