# Xcode 6.0/6.1 and building with client's provisioning profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I downloaded the latest Xcode 6.1 and with having my client's provisioning profile/certificate, I tried to build IPA file for them (for ad-hoc deployment) but in the new Xcode 6.1 when you start archiving, it tries to connect to my apple developer account and since my client's App Id doesn't exist, it says:
Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues: An App ID with identifier 'com.myclient.something' is not available. Please enter a different string.

I used to do the same thing in Xcode 5.1.1 and I could archive and create the IPA file for my client with their provisioning profile. DO you know guys how can I build the IPA file for their in-house distribution in Xcode 6.1?
Thanks in advance,
Cam

Comment: Do you have the private key for the certificate?

Comment: Yes Of course.in Xcode, I do the code signing. select my client's provisioing and code sign identity then select Archive menu item and finally when the organizer window is up, i select Export...Save for Ad Hoc Deployement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Ad-hoc builds in Xcode 6 without signing in to developer account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842165/make-ad-hoc-builds-in-xcode-6-without-signing-in-to-developer-account)

Answer (score 6):

Locate your .xcarchive file. Right click on it and select Show Package Contents. In the Products/Application folder you will find your app. Drag it onto the iTunes. iTunes will add it to the Applications tab. Go to the Applications tab in iTunes. Right click on your app and select Show In Finder. There you have your .ipa file